# Global error handling in Android application with Roboguice

Tags: android, error-handling, roboguice

I'm working on a Android app which uses the [Roboguice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) dependency injection framework.
So most of the time we extend RoboActivity, RoboListActivity and similar.

Now I would like to introduce some sort of global error handling which will show some alert or a error activity in case the application crashes.

I have done this before by implementing a base activity like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new GeneralError(this));
}
```

where I define the default exception handler and all other activities then derived from this one.

Now I'm wondering how this is achieved with Roboguice?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some rough psuedo code that should get you started.  It uses the [roboguice events](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/Events) to make some of these cross cutting concerns a little easier.

```
public class GlobalErrorHandler {
  // injects the current activity here
  @Inject Context context;


  public void onCreate(@Observes OnCreateEvent e) {
    // Wires up the error handling
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new GeneralError(context));
  }
}

public class MySpecificActivity {
  // required in every activity that needs error handling
  @Inject GlobalErrorHandler errorHandler;

}
```